# Derivative of $\sin (2x)\cos(3x)$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

> What is the derivative of $\sin (2x)\cos(3x)?$

Is it 

 $\cos (2x) \cos(3x)-\sin (2x) \sin(3x)$
 or 
$2\cos (2x) \cos(3x)-3\sin (2x) \sin(3x)?$

The answer is given the latter but I only get the former.

Please offer your assistance for the same.
Thankyou

Comment: Hint: What is the derivative of the function $x\mapsto\sin(2x)$

Comment: cos(2x) right? and derivetive of cos(3x) is -sin(3x)

Comment: No, not right. Which definition of derivative are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've noticed that you need to use the product rule, but don't forget to use [chain rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule)! For example,

$$\bigl(\sin(f(x))\bigr)'=\cos(f(x))\cdot f'(x)$$

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**

Complete
$$(\cos(ax))'=\cdots\quad;\quad (\sin(ax))'=\cdots$$
and :
$$(f\times g)'=\cdots$$
Apply these results.

**Answer**

> $(\cos(ax))'=-a\sin(ax)\quad;\quad (\sin(ax))'=a\cos(ax)\quad;\quad (f\times g)'=f'g+g'f$ so we apply: $(\sin(2x)\cos(3x))'=(\sin(2x))'\cos(3x)+\sin(2x)(\cos(3x))'=2\cos (2x) \cos(3x)-3\sin (2x) \sin(3x)$

Comment: Yes after application I got the first result

Comment: No you have a mistake. Verify you result what's the derivative of $\cos(ax)$?

Comment: It is not -sin(ax)?

Comment: No look at the answer.

Comment: how do you do that answer box?

Comment: Okay now I got the formula for derivative of sin(ax) thnx

Comment: @yankeefan11 Just write >!

Comment: You're welcome @chndn

Answer (score 2):

The product rule states:
$$\frac d {dx}(f(x)\times g(x))=f'(x)\times g(x) + g'(x)\times f(x)$$
So let f(x) = sin(2x) and g(x) = cos (3x).  You should be familiar with the derivative of sin(ax) and cos(ax), so just plug those in.

Useful:

$$\frac d {dx} \sin(ax) = a\cos(ax)$$
$$\frac d {dx} \cos(ax) = -a\sin(ax)$$

Comment: I know all that but I am not familiar with the derivative of sin(ax) and cos(ax)

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

Why don't we use $$2\sin B\cos A=\sin(A+B)-\sin(A-B)$$ to find $$2\sin2A\cos3A=\sin5A-\sin A$$